# Woocommerce - Convert Delivery method into a custom field

Tags: plugin-development, woocommerce-offtopic, custom-field

Woocommerce  -  Integration into Sage Accounts

So currently we have available analysis field in sage, which means we can use customer fields in the basket to import into Sage Accounts, so for example we use "Customer Purchase order number" as analysis1 so that this then gets imported into Sage

However, what I need is within the order itself, is to take the field value of the delivery method chosen by the customer, and duplicate this under the meta of analysis2

Comment: When you're sending the info to SAGE why not just grab it from the shipping method field rather than mapping the data and duplicating it to a second field?

Comment: Because Sage will only allow custom fields called analysis1, analysis2 and analysis3 to be imported into orders no other fields allow us to import custom content

Comment: That doesn’t mean you have to duplicate your data though. When you send to Sage you’re using JSON correct, so you can use ‘analysis2 : shipping_method’ or however you need to structure it.  That way all you need to do is get the info rather than get it, save it as a new field, and then submit it.

Comment: So can I add a field in the order meta (or what ever you call it, like as you've said 'analysis2 : shipping_method' and where would this go